# Ordering rows in a parent table by SUM of column in a child table

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have 3 tables in my database

```
companies{
id,
name,
address
}

stores{
id,
name,
address,
company_id
}

invoices{
id,
total,
date_time,
store_id
}
```

As you can see, each store is connected to a company via foreign key, also each invoice is connected to a store.

My question is, how can i write a SQL query which will return all stores by a company and order them by their turnover?

If i use the query:

```
SELECT s.*,
sum(i.total) as turnover FROM store s
JOIN invoices i
ON i.store_id = s.id 
WHERE YEAR(i.date_time) = 2019;
```

I can see the turnover for one store for a year 2019 for example, but i'm struggling to find a way to get a list of store ordered by their turnover for a certain period.

Comment: The `turnover` expression you just created is visible to the `ORDER BY` clause. Why can't you use it there, by adding `ORDER BY turnover DESC`?

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to join all 3 tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  companies c
  INNER JOIN stores s on s.company_id = c.id
  INNER JOIN invoices i ON i.store_id = s.id
```

That's your entire raw data in detailed list. Then you say you want it for a certain company only:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  companies c
  INNER JOIN stores s on s.company_id = c.id
  INNER JOIN invoices i ON i.store_id = s.id 
WHERE c.name = 'Acme Rubber Co'
```

Then you only want the stores and the invoices amounts:

```
SELECT s.name, i.total
FROM 
  companies c
  INNER JOIN stores s on s.company_id = c.id
  INNER JOIN invoices i ON i.store_id = s.id 
WHERE c.name = 'Acme Rubber Co'
```

Then you want a row set where each line is a single store and the sum of all invoices for that store:

```
SELECT s.name, SUM(i.total)
FROM 
  companies c
  INNER JOIN stores s on s.company_id = c.id
  INNER JOIN invoices i ON i.store_id = s.id 
WHERE c.name = 'Acme Rubber Co'
GROUP BY s.name
```

Lastly you want them in descending order, highest total first:

```
SELECT s.name as storename, SUM(i.total) as turnover
FROM 
  companies c
  INNER JOIN stores s on s.company_id = c.id
  INNER JOIN invoices i ON i.store_id = s.id 
WHERE c.name = 'Acme Rubber Co'
GROUP BY s.name
ORDER BY turnover DESC
```

The order of evaluation in sql is FROM(with joins), WHERE, GROUP BY, SELECT, ORDER BY which is why I use different names in eg the order by than I do in the group by. Conceptually your db only sees the names of things as output by the immediately previous operation. Mysql isn't actually too picky but some db are - you couldn't say `GROUP BY storename` in sql server because the SELECT that creates the storename alias hasn't been run at the time the group by is done

Note: I wasn't really sure on what you were looking for in a WHERE - you started by saying "all stores turnover for a certain company" and finished saying you were "struggling to get turnover for a period"

If you want a period, use eg `WHERE somedatecolumn BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2000-12-31'` (Between is inclusive) or `WHERE somedatecolumn >= '2000-01-01' AND somedatecolumn < '2001-01-01'` (A good pattern to use if the date includes a time too).  It is almost never wise to call a function on a column you're searching with, ie do not do `WHERE YEAR(somedatecolumn) = 2000` because it disables indexing on the column and makes the search very slow

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick and easy to understand answer!

Comment: No probs! I added a footnote about searching btw

Comment: I actually need to use a combination of those, i need to search for a certain company for a certain period.  I am making a java app with a console interface as my internship project, where a user can type something like appname report --company <name> --month/quarter <> --year <> and then get a report as .xlsx file, so that's why i was using year() function.

Comment: The recommendations I gave for searching a date range that is the whole of the year 2000 will work exactly the same as using YEAR() to extract the year and comparing it to 2000. The point i was making is "If you search like `WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN datefrom AND dateto` then an index on datecolumn CAN be used. If you search like `WHERE somefunction(column) = somevalue` than an index on datecol CANNOT be used". Never call functions on table data in a where clause if you can avoid it, and in this case you can easily avoid it. This is something to remember for your whole career, not just this now

Comment: *unless you use a database that supports function indexing; few do and it is rarely set up. See http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/function_based_indexes - but err on the side of caution; don't call functions on columns in where clauses